# Make SharePoint Page as Home Page or Default page

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile

I have five different Hub sites and I would like to put a option for users, when the option 1 is clicked the Hub site 1 will become default home page and when user opens the bowser it will be default home page.

How to set them in user profile and if needed they can switch to Hub site 2 and remove Hub site 1 under their profile